# c# execute a method from Form in the MainForm

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

Well, I'm not sure that the title was really clear so let's explain it with an exemple:

Here is the mathod that open the WinForm when clicked...

```
namespace STS
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        /*---------- SHOW DATABASE ----------*/
        private void showDataBasesToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ShowDataBase db = new ShowDataBase();
            db.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code executed when the WinForm exit. That's the moment when I want it to call a method in the MainForm.

...And here are the errors...

```
namespace STS
{
    public partial class ShowDataBase : Form
    {
        /*----------  ----------*/
        private void ShowDataBase_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            /*I've try this but error: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property*/
            MainForm.plotMarks();

            /*And this but error: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter*/
            MainForm mF = new MainForm();
            // With: MainForm mF = new MainForm(this); //--> No error but it execute another Form than the one I want (my splashScreen in this case)...
            mF.plotMarks()
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the method that I wanna call:

```
namespace STS
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public void plotMarks()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hello");
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Dimitri

Comment: You need to call the form instance, not the class.plotMarks..

Comment: Hi, thanks for your interest.. I'm looking to the exemple you give me. I will come back to you.

Comment: Well... I'm trully sorry... I'should have search better... Thx to you all!